# Calculate the largets and smallest number fiven exp, bias, and fract

Tags: architecture, floating-point

Give 8 bits total, where 3 bits are `exp bits`, 4 bits are `frac bits` and 1 for `sign bit`. Have to find the largest and smallest values.

```
0 110 1111 - largest
1 110 1111 - smallest

1) E = exponent - Bias = 6 - 7 = -1
2) M = 1 + f = 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 = 31/16

Value = (-1)^s * M * 2^E = 31/16 + 1/2 = 2.4375 - largest value
                                        -2.4375 - smallest value
```

Is this correct? Im not sure about it because im getting a "small" number as a largest value ?

Comment: With "smallest", the smallest magnitude may be meant, i.e. 0 or the value just above it (`0 000 0001` or `M = 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1/16`, `exp = -7`, so that would be `2^-11 = 0.00048828125`). But with a maximum value of 7 for the exponent, why is the bias 7 and not, say, 3? And how do you get to `2.4375`? I would get something like `0.96875` for your values.

Comment: FWIW, it should be `31/16 * 1/2 = 0.96875`, not `31/16 + 1/2 = ...`.

Comment: Voting to close: there isn't enough information here about this fictional format to be able to answer. Just knowing the number of exponent bits and fraction bits isn't enough. Are we to assume that this is an IEEE 754-style format, with gradual underflow, infinities, nans, hidden bit, etc? If so, please state that clearly!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you chose your bias at 7, but that way you won't be able to get large values.

Choose a bias of 3. And make the exponent 7, then you get:

```
0 111 1111 - largest
```

This is

```
M = 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 = 31/16
E = 7 - 3 --> 2^4 = 16
```

So your large value becomes `31/16 * 16 = 31`.

The "smallest" (positive) value would be

```
0 000 0001 - smallest

M = 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1/16 = 17/16
E = 0 - 3 --> 2^-3 = 1/8
```

So your small value becomes `17/16 * 1/8 = 17/128 = 0.1328125`

Of course, with a sign bit of 1, you get the negatives of these values.

And I would count all zero bits (`0 000 0000`) as +zero, or just a sign bit set (`1 000 0000`) as -zero.